How to simulate Planet orbits with Rigid Bodies
I've done the typical simulation of Sun/Earth/Moon orbiting each other by using the "Follow Path" constraint, which is simple after watching a few tutorials.
But then I asked myself if I could do the same by using Rigid Bodies simulation only.
So I created a Motor and a Hinge RB-constraint in between Sun & Earth, allowing the Earth to orbit around the sun, and I did the same in between Earth and Moon, but parenting the empties for these 2 constraints with the Earth, just to make sure that they travel along Earth's orbit.
Surprisingly, the Earth's rotation is 'irregular' (goes back and forth) instead of having a constant movement around the Sun.
Can anyone suggest what's wrong with this scenario?
Thanks a lot in advance!!



Not surprisingly, this is indeed how planets orbit. The moon "does" make the Earth wobble, the difference is that there is a greater difference in mass, so the Earth's wobbling is little. What is actually wrong there is the "hinge" that is not allowing the earth to wobble in the radial direction of the sun. A real simulation would need radial fields of "acceleration" with quadratic falloff, each field at the center of each object. --- But to fix your simulation, decrease the moon's mass or increase the earths mass, or both

Thanks a lot @DanielMöller, actually by playing with Earth & Moon's masses and motor speeds too, I can get a much more fluent movement. But I was not intending to create a fully realistic simulation (in fact orbits are circles and the 3 bodies are on the same flat level, without any axis deviation), instead I just wanted to learn if the 2 motors could act independently. What I've learnt is that rigid bodies do consider all masses and distances, so probably this is not the best way to generate independent movements in the animation, but the "Follow Path" constraint is the way forward.
